# Commit previous local commit before latest revisions - Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository, commit

I have an iOS app that I connected to a GitHub repository. I tried to make a commit on the 14th November 2016, but it failed as my GitHub account was suspended (due to payment issues). I have now fixed the issues I was having with my GitHub repository.

If I look at the "Workspace History" screen in Xcode, I can see that Xcode saved the commit locally. Since then I have made further changes to the app files.

So my question is, if I try to commit again to GitHub, will Xcode push the current commits **AND** the commits from 14th Nov 2016... **OR**... will Xcode just push the latest modifications and **NOT** the changes made in the 14th Nov 2016 commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your old commit was done in branch `master` and you continue to commit in the same branch. Now you push the branch changes to Github. As a result ALL commits (in this branch) will be copied there.

Comment: Great thanks and yes I am using the master branch only.